# Creating Product Programtically results empty Product name

Tags: magento-1.9

If **Registered user** click on button, we are creating Product Programatically. but when **guest user** click on button , its creating product with **empty product name**

button :

```
<button  onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo 
Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\',
event);setrequestlogin();"  
id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >SAVE DESIGN</button>
```

**controllers**

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave=true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath="") 
{       
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        $product->setName($originalProduct->getName()); 
        $product->setDescription('what ever you need here');

        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);      

        if ($doSave)
            $product->save();

        return $product;
    }
```

I tried below code, but didt worked for me

```
if($_category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category && $_category->getId()):

        $product->setName($originalProduct->getName()); 

        endif;
```

full controllers : https://pastebin.com/Gn6iMwug

**Edit**

when **Registered user** upload image or text and click on "Save Design" button in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-7.html) , than Product creating with "Product Name".

[image]

When **Guest user** upload image or text and click on "Save Design" button in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-7.html) , it will ask to login, once **Guest login/register** , Product is creating with **empty Product name**

[image]

After clicking save design, it redirect to another page :

[image]

Comment: Can you add your login popup phtml code?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya please check :  https://pastebin.com/GR5eyFwK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will only resolve your product Name issue.**
Update your form `action` code to below.

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect', array('_secure'=>(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on'), 'id' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId())) ?>
```

The product is being created without name is because you are not passing variable `id` which is required in your `createSimpleProductAndRedirect` function.

Comment: I thought when we pass : `example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect` , than thats going to be enough..... thanks a lot.....

Answer (score 1):

I looked through your code and this is normal behavior.

Your `$_category` variable is never assigned.
This means that the condition `$_category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` will always return `false`.
Because of that, your line `$product->setName($originalProduct->getName());`  will never get executed and you end up with a product without a name.
I'm not sure what you are trying to do, because you code looks fuzzy, but I'm sure that's why the problem appears.

Comment: thanks , I will dig deeper on this & come back to you....

Comment: updated question, when you get free time, please check once.....

Comment: you added nothing relevant. I already told you what the problem is. Enable your error reporting and you will see your coding errors on the screen. This is basic PHP. You are using a variable that is not initialized.

Comment: oh sorry, i will check it.....